# C++ - What does reference& operator= do here

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across this piece of code while reading some stuff about vectors in C++11 STL. It uses an assignment of operator=. Now i can't figure out exactly what it does.

Here is the code :

```
namespace std {

    template <typename Allocator> class vector<bool, Allocator> {
    public:
        // auxiliary proxy type for element modifications:

        class reference {
            ...
        public:
            reference& operator=(const bool ) noexcept; // assignments
            reference& operator=(const reference&) noexcept;
            operator bool( ) const noexcept; // automatic type conversion to bool
            void flip( ) noexcept;
            // bit complement
        };
        ...
        // operations for element access return reference proxy instead of bool:
        reference operator[]( size_type idx );
        reference at( size_type idx );
        reference front( );
        reference back( );

    };
}
```

From the above code i can understand that it returns a type of class reference. But what i can't understand is this statement `reference& operator=(const reference&) noexcept;` . 
Please let me know what is the actual meaning of this statement in this context

Comment: Its a copy constructor: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Comment: @Ben: No, it's an assignment operator. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `reference` class is what's known as a *proxy*, it masquerades as another type to give it behaviors you couldn't get otherwise. In this case it's substituting for `bool`, thus it needs to be assignable to `bool`. You can see that there are two `operator=` methods on this class, one that takes `bool` and one that takes `reference&`.

One of the rules for `operator=` is that it must return a reference to the object, so that you can chain the `=` operators:

```
b1 = b2 = false;
```

Comment: Quite clear explanation . Thanks a lot. Now i understand its application. Can it be called as a type of polymorphism ? As the proxy class can act as multiple types.

Comment: @Maxx I don't think polymorphism is quite the right way to describe it but I can't put into words why I think so.

Answer (score 3):

Use of `reference` as a class is a poor choice. But...

The function

```
reference& operator=(const bool ) noexcept;
```

returns a reference to an object of type `reference`. Most likely, the return statement in the function looks like:

```
return *this;
```

Take a simple class:

```
struct A
{
   A(int in) : data(in) {}
   A& operator=(int in)
   {
      data = in;
      return *this;
   }

   A& operator=(A const& rhs)
   {
      data = rhs.data;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

Usage:

```
A a(10); // a.data is 10
a = 20;  // a.data is 20
A b(5);  // b.data is 5
a = b = 35; // a.data as well as b.data are 35
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right that it returns a `reference` object (Actually it returns a reference to a `reference` object - that's what the `&` means).

The method name indicates that you're overloading the assignment operator `=`.

The parameter to the method means that it takes an immutable (the `const` keyword) reference to a `reference` object.

The `noexcept` keyword promises that the method will not throw an exception. If you break that promise, it your program will throw a runtime exception.

C++ programmers would interpret this as a copy assignment operator.